# docker-compose set environment per-service profile

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, integration-testing

I recently discovered [docker-compose profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921624/4541045), which seem great for allowing optional local resources for testing

However, it's not clear if it's possible to provide a container with a different environment depending on the profile; what is a sensible way (if any) to switch environmental vars by-service profile?

Perhaps

- using `extends` (which appears deprecated, but may work for me anyways [Extend service in docker-compose 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279662/extend-service-in-docker-compose-3))
- the profile value is or can be made available to the container so it can switch internally
- this was never intended or considered in the design (probe local connection on startup, volume mounting tricks..)

---

Specifically, I'm trying to prefer an address and some keys via env var under some testing profile, but prefer a `.env` file otherwise.

Normal structure

```
services:
  webapp:
    ...
    env_file:
     - .env
```

Structure with `test` profile

```
services:
  db-service:
    image: db-image
    profiles: ["test"]
    ...
  webapp:
    ...
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db-service:1234
```

Answer (score 7):

I can say with certainty that this was never an intended use case for profiles :)

`docker-compose` has no native way to pass the current profile down to a service. As a workaround you could pass the `COMPOSE_PROFILES` environment variable to the container. But this does not work when specifying the profiles with the  `--profiles` flag on the command line.
Also you had to manually handle having *multiple* active profiles corretly.

The best solution for your specific issue would be to have different services for each profile:

```yaml
services:
  webapp-prod:
    profiles: ["prod"]
    #...
    env_file:
     - .env

  db-service:
    image: db-image
    profiles: ["test"]
    #...

  webapp-test:
    profiles: ["test"]
    #...
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db-service:1234
```

This only has the downside of different service names for "the same" service with different configurations and they both need assigned profile(s) so none of them will start by default, i.e. with every profile.

Also it has some duplicate code for the two service definitions. If you want to share the definition in the file you could use [yaml anchors and aliases](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd):

```yaml
services:
  webapp-prod: &webapp
    profiles: ["prod"]
    #...
    env_file:
     - .env

  webapp-test:
    <<: *webapp
    profiles: ["test"]
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db-service:1234

  db-service:
    image: db-image
    profiles: ["test"]
    #...
```

---

Another alternative could be [using multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files):

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  webapp:
    #...
    env_file:
     - .env
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.test.yml
services:
  db-service:
    image: db-image
    #...

  webapp:
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db-service:1234
```

This way you can start the production service normally and the instances by passing and merging the compose files:

```sh
docker-compose up # start the production version
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml # start the test version
```

Comment: oh, it's been a minute since I was looking at this, but I do think multiple profiles is the right answer if they can override keys!

Comment: Multiple services or multiple compose files are great ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arcan's answers has a lot of good ideas.

I think another solution is to just pass a variable next to your --profile tag on your docker commands. You can then for instance set an -e TESTING=.env.testing in your docker-compose command and use `env_file:${TESTING:-.env.default}` in your file. This allows you to have a default env file added on any none profile actions and runs the given file when needed.

Since I have a slightly different setup I am adding a single variable to a container in my docker-compose so I did not test if it works on the `env-file:` attribute but I think it should work.